# checking an array with input from user to make sure non numeric are restricted php

Tags: php

I have this program on php to look for min, max, Av and sort numbers with input from user. But then i use intval on readline to ask question and all values are return as integers and non numeric values are considered zero. but then i dont want it this way. i want user to enter only numeric values and non numeric values should throw an error.
i try foreach and if statements but it didnt work. Please is there another function that can better test the readline string  than intval?

```
    **$value = 0;
$notGood = true;
while($notGood){
    $value = intval(readline("How many numbers do you want in the list:"));
    if ($value > 0){
        $notGood = false;
    }else{
        echo "You need to input integer greater than zero";
    }
}
$arr = array();
for($j = 0; $j < $value; $j++){
    $arr[$j] = intval(readline("input number ".($j+1).": "));
    // if(!is_numeric($j){
        // echo"Fault";
        
    // }
     foreach($j as $element){
        if(!is_numeric($element)){
              echo var_export($element, true) . " is not numeric, enter an integer", PHP_EOL;
             continue;
        }
    }
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ((int)$arr[$j]==$arr[$j]) echo "Is number"; 
   else echo "Isn't a number";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php) would be a good solution :

```
for($j = 0; $j < $value; $j++){
    while(!$arr[$j] = preg_match('/^\d+$/',readline("input number ".($j+1).": ")));
}
```

Place the above code in place of

```
for($j = 0; $j < $value; $j++){
    $arr[$j] = intval(readline("input number ".($j+1).": "));
    // if(!is_numeric($j){
        // echo"Fault";
        
    // }
     foreach($j as $element){
        if(!is_numeric($element)){
              echo var_export($element, true) . " is not numeric, enter an integer", PHP_EOL;
             continue;
        }
    }
}
```

(Remove the code above and paste the given solution)